# Joda DateTime getDayOfYear() method returning 366 for 2013-12-31T23:59:52.000Z when it should be 365

Tags: java, datetime

My program is halting and printing out this error:

```
org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Value 366 for dayOfYear must be in the range [1,365]
at org.joda.time.field.FieldUtils.verifyValueBounds(FieldUtils.java:217)
at org.joda.time.field.PreciseDurationDateTimeField.set(PreciseDurationDateTimeField.java:78)
at org.joda.time.chrono.ZonedChronology$ZonedDateTimeField.set(ZonedChronology.java:466)
at org.joda.time.DateTime.withDayOfYear(DateTime.java:1716)
```

The date is

```
2013-12-31T23:59:52.000Z
```

Day of year should be 365.  Why is Joda returning 366 and then throwing an error?

EDIT

The rest of the error just has information about my class:

```
at MainProgram.processMinuteLevelAGCRecords(MainProgram.java:405)
at MainProgram.createMinuteLevelAGCFile(MainProgram.java:274)
at MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:106)
```

The code trying to get the day of year looks like this as I need julian date in the format "yyDDD":

```
Integer.parseInt(String.format("%04d", date.getYear()).substring(2)
            + String.format("%03d", date.getDayOfYear()));
```

The "date" at the time this is failing is:

```
2013-12-31T23:59:52.000Z
```

Line 405 is

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(0).withYear(year).withDayOfYear(day).withHourOfDay(0).withMinuteOfHour(‌​0).withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
```

EDIT 2

I have a DateTime object derived from a timestamp retrieved from a database.  My DateTime objects is called "date".  When I print out "date", I get

```
date = 2013-12-31T23:59:52.000Z
```

Now, more code using the DateTime object "date" from above:

```
int julianDay = Integer.parseInt(String.format("%04d", date.getYear()).substring(2)
            + String.format("%03d", date.getDayOfYear()));
int year = julianDay/1000;
year = Integer.parseInt(startDate.substring(0,2) + Integer.toString(year));
int day = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(julianDay).substring(2));
DateTime dt = new DateTime(0).withYear(year).withDayOfYear(day).withHourOfDay(0).withMinuteOfHour(0).withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
```

And it fails at the last line above because of day 366.

Comment: It appears from the traceback that you're attempting to init a DateTime object withDayOfYear(366).  What is the line below the last line above?

Comment: Show the code (yours) that is causing the exception.

Comment: 2013 wasn't a leap year, was it?

Comment: @Hannes - A leap year is divisible by 4.

Comment: Show the stack trace.  (And the above code is utter nonsense.)

Comment: Show us the code around line 405.

Comment: Please see edits above.  Also, please bear with me - I am debugging someone else's code.  I realize that date.toString("yyDDD") actually gives me what I need, but when I use that instead, other calculations down the line come out wrong.  Line 405 is DateTime dt = new DateTime(0).withYear(year).withDayOfYear(day).withHourOfDay(0).withMinuteOfHour(0).withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));

Comment: You try to set dayOfYear to 366 on 2013, which is not a leap year. Please check the value of the variables year and day.

Comment: @Hannes - Correct.  Which is why I am wondering why getDayOfYear() is returning 366 in the first place.

Comment: `DateTime dt` does not match `date`. Which is it?

Comment: And what's the value of "day" arriving at line 405???

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm sorry I meant to clarify - date is just a DateTime object called date.  i.e. DateTime date = ....   The Value of day at line 405 when the program fails is 366.  It should be 365 though.

Comment: Looks like you invalidly derived the 366 value, doesn't it??

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, that's my issue.  Why would getDayOfYear() return 366 when there are only 365 days in 2013?

Comment: You've not shown us that indeed getDayOfYear *is* returning 366.  You've not given us any hint as to how the value 366 is being derived!!

Comment: (Will someone please put this question out of its misery!!)

Comment: @HotLicks Please see Edit 2 above for more code information on how 366 is being derived.  Does this clarify?

Comment: You're right, that's some amazingly screwy code.  Why are you constantly converting back and forth between `int` and `String`?

Comment: If your listing is to be believed, julianDay is 2013365.  That would make day be 13365, not 365.  It is a strange failure, alright.

Comment: OK, missed the substring, so julianDay would be 13365 (which is a little weird, but what the hey?).  But since you have `date` up there, why are you not simply using it, vs doing all those senseless conversions?

Comment: In any event, add println statements to print out julianDay, year, and day.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is clearly not in Joda-Time:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DateTime d = new DateTime(2013,12,31,23,59,52,DateTimeZone.UTC);
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(d.getDayOfYear());
}
```

prints

```
2013-12-31T23:59:52.000Z
365
```

I suggest you single-step through your code with an IDE debugger.

(I know this is probably more of a comment than an answer but it's hard to put readable code in a comment)

Answer (score 0):

```
int julianDay = ((date.getYear() % 100) * 1000) + date.getDayOfYear();  // If you really need this

DateTime dt = new DateTime(0).withYear(date.getYear()).withDayOfYear(date.getDayOfYear()).withHourOfDay(0).withMinuteOfHour(0).withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
```

(Unsure of all that timezone stuff at the end -- Joda Time is not my thing.)